# Single Images will show but multiple images will not using Python Turtle library

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics

I have come up with a problem that then i try to put multiple images on a screen only the latest image will show.

```
AntiAirMissleLauncherRed(200,-200)
InfantryRed(-200,200)
JeepRed(-200,-200)
```

I have put different co-ordinates in each of the images so they should of appeared at different places on the screen. However turtle just moves to the next location instead of printing the image.
[The last Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIpam.png)

This is the code that i have used to make the images appear onto the screen:

```
def InfantryRed(x,y):

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()

    RedInfantry = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a level computer science\\Coursework\\Week\\Red team\\InfantryRedV20.gif"

    screen.addshape(RedInfantry)
    turtle.shape(RedInfantry)
```

When printing these images individually each of them show up but when trying to print multiple images onto the same screen it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the turtle commands correctly.  Depending on whether your images are permanently stationary, or need to move, you need to approach this differently.

First, permanently stationary:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RedInfantry = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\a level computer science\Coursework\Week\Red team\InfantryRedV20.gif"

def InfantryRed(x, y):
    turtle.shape(RedInfantry)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    return turtle.stamp()  # leave a lasting impression

screen = Screen()
screen.addshape(RedInfantry)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()

infantry_1 = InfantryRed(200, -200)
infantry_2 = InfantryRed(-200, 200)
infantry_3 = InfantryRed(-200, -200)

turtle.clearstamp(infantry_1)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Fill in your other image paths with matching `screen.addshape()` calls.  You won't be able to move the above images but if you want to eventually delete them, keep track of what `stamp()` returns.

If you want to be able to move (and hide) your images, then you need to assign them each a turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RedInfantry = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\a level computer science\Coursework\Week\Red team\InfantryRedV20.gif"

def InfantryRed(x, y):
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.shape(RedInfantry)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    return turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.addshape(RedInfantry)

infantry_1 = InfantryRed(200, -200)
infantry_2 = InfantryRed(-200, 200)
infantry_3 = InfantryRed(-200, -200)

infantry_1.goto(200, 200)

screen.exitonclick()
```